# Change Springboot Actuator service management port via Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As following I can change the server port, is there a way to make same thing for actuator management service port.

I know similar ways to change to the via system parameter, adding management.port=XXX into application.properties.

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Profile("dev")
public class AppConfig {

   Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);

   @Autowired
   DBPropertyBean dbPropertyBean;

   private @Value("${webserver.port}")
   int serverPort;


   @Bean
   public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
      TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
      factory.setPort(serverPort);
      return factory;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, If you deep into the sources, for the `management.port=XXX` is just auto-confiure the `ManagementServerProperties` bean, so with the JavaConfig, just inject the `ManagementServerProperties` and config the port. ( As demo, I hardcode all the ports. )

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig {
    private int serverPort = 8081;

    @Autowired
    private ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties;

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.setPort(serverPort);

        if (managementServerProperties != null)
            managementServerProperties.setPort(8089);

        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mmc18 Can you add more info about this?

Comment: sorry for late, Spring keep serving at server.port event though I set manegement port via managementServerProperties ->setPort

Comment: @mmc18 It's working on spring boot 1.4.2, or `@Order` , `@AutoConfigureOrder` can be used here.